# Customize font awesome icons?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome, jquery-confirm

I am using warning icon of font awesome in my jquery-confirm plugin

The confirm popup working fine, but the thing is that we need a black exclamatory instead of white in warning icon

I am using below code in my project

```
icon: 'fa fa-warning'
```

Is there any way to customize that font awesome icon?

[want to turn the white exclamatory into black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scEat.png)

[I need to set jquery-confirm icon like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3h8x.png)

Answer (score 1):

essentially font-awesome is an icon font, which means you can treat every icon as a character in a font. So

```
.font-awesome-icon{
    color:black;
}
```

will work for you. just make sure you use your own css classname instead of `.font-awesome-icon`

Comment: but i am using icon: 'fa fa-warning' code in the jquery-conffirm dialog. How can i switch over like your way?

Comment: add an extra class to your class attribute like this, `<i class="fa fa-warning black-ico"></i>`. then add css like this `.black-ico { color:black; }`

Comment: Thanks @Jason Freeman, your suggestion is working fine. but I need the icon like below only exclamatory mark should be black and remains are same. now I edited my post